# generate texture by interacting with another mesh

Tags: mesh, texturing, materials, add-on, shaders

Hello Blender Community,

I have a scene where i want to generate a texture on mesh A by letting it interact with another mesh B. The goal is that i don't have to animate the texture by hand and everything is in real-time so i only have to keyframe Mesh B.

You can imagine it like when you're writing on paper: the part of the pen that touches the paper will turn it into another color.

In my case the Pen would be mesh B and the paper is mesh A.

Currently I can't think of any way to do that within Blender so i was hoping that somebody could recommend me an addon or a phython script.

Kind of like in the picture shown below:

[image: Picture Description]

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about what is expected for the pen 'special shader'? Is it just a color or something more complicated?

Comment: I was hoping that it is a texture or a black/white factor like you can find in blender

Comment: @lemon .. I was thinking.. just Dynamic Paint, but I can't for the life of me get it working in my recent build of 2.8? Is this a known issue?

Comment: @RobinBetts, I don't know. Here it really depends on what Dino wants. As it is to generate a texture, that may be a live paint tool. But why not using native paint tools? Maybe Dino will tell us.

Comment: OK, got it working ... At first sight, it looks as though [Dynamic Paint](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/dynamic_paint/introduction.html) is made to do what you're asking for.. maybe a variation of the answers [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/124117/35559) or [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/123238/35559). The color information generated and stored either in a UV, or in vertex colors, could be used to mask/influence any other texture in a shader tree..

Comment: I've already tried it with Dynamic Paint and/or Vertex Paint but if I use them the Animation won't be real time anymore and i would have to redraw every frame for it to work. And in an Animation that is 10 minutes long I that would be alot of effort.